# Handling Mongoose Disconnect

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose 4.13.7

I want to connect to mongo but if an error occurs I want to reconnect. 
But after 5 reconnects, if an error occurs, the process should exit.

This is the code:

```
var count = 0;
handleDisconnect();
function handleDisconnect(){
    count++;
    console.log('Trying to connect to mongo. Attempt : ' + count);
    mongoose.connect(config.mongo.uri,{useMongoClient:true});
    mongoose.connection.on('error',(error)=>{
        if (count >= 5){
            console.log('Mongo ERROR');
            console.error(error);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        else{
            setTimeout(handleDisconnect,1000);  
        }
    });
    mongoose.connection.on('open',()=>{
        console.log('Connected to mongo at ' + Date.now());
    });
}
```

I have posted the output of the code as well. I don't understand how the attempt count is exceeding 5? There is also a memory leak warning and node:6804 error message. What am I doing wrong?

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUdXL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attach an event listener for the `error` event each time the event is emitted. This causes the memory leak warning and also makes the callback function run multiple times per each event ocurrance. You should not add the event handler inside the `handleDisconnect()` funciton.

Example:

```
function handleDisconnect(mongoError) {
  // check error reason, increment counters, check if errors limit reached
}

mongoose.connection.on('error', handleDisconnect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check disconnected event when Mongoose lost connection to the MongoDB server. This event may be due to your code explicitly closing the connection, the database server crashing, or network connectivity issues.

```
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => console.log('Server disconnected from mongoDB'));
```

error Event: Emitted if an error occurs on a connection, like a parseError due to malformed data or a payload larger than 16MB.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection-events